# VideoView Android. How play video without stoping other video/audio tracks?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

> When I playing video in activity, other apps are stoping playing audio/video.

```
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +    getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"
                +  splash_vid);

        splashvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        splashvideo.setZOrderOnTop(false);
        splashvideo.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        splashvideo.setVideoURI(video);
        splashvideo.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> jumpBack());
        splashvideo.requestFocus();
        splashvideo.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        splashvideo.setOnErrorListener(this);
        splashvideo.start();
        splashvideo.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        splashvideo.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

Comment: did you find solution for it?